# Option add in multiselect box using bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my loading page I am trying to add options to a multi select box, but when I append to the select box it's not added.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var masterobj = [{
    "employee_name": "headthree",
    "employee_id": "203"
  }];

  $('#ddlPermission').multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    maxHeight: 100,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    dropRight: true
  });
  
  $(".clickbutton").click(function() {
    $('#ddlPermission').val(['A', 'B']);
    $('#ddlPermission').multiselect("refresh");
  });

  $.each(masterobj, function(key, value) {
    $('.multiselect')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value.employee_id)
        .text(value.employee_name));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input class="form-control btn-primary clickbutton" type="button" name="select" id="select" value="Click">
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <select id="ddlPermission" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="permission_ddl">
  <option value="201">headone</option>
  <option value="202">headtwo</option>
</select>
  <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="myFunction()" class="button active myfunction" value="Submit">
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ramumothukuri/kxbbtgwL/)

I need to append the options to the `multiselect` box while loading the page.

Comment: @pedram why downvoted?

Comment: Please always include your code within the question. I edited in for you this time

Comment: It wasn't me @ramu

Comment: @McCrossan Sure, i am  getting error while upload code within the question. I don't now the problem thats why i given url. Here after i will put code here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as I've already edited the code in to the question for you

Comment: @McCrossan Here after i will put code here. now everything fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, your problem is you should append data before `initialize` multiselect

```js
// bootstrap multiselect box
$(document).ready(function() {

var masterobj = [{"employee_name":"headthree","employee_id":"203"}];

   $.each(masterobj, function(key, value) {   
     $('.multiselect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value.employee_id)
                    .text(value.employee_name)); 
});

  $('#ddlPermission').multiselect({
    buttonWidth : '100%',
    maxHeight : 100,
    includeSelectAllOption : true,
    dropRight : true
  });  
 $(".clickbutton").click(function(){ 
   $('#ddlPermission').val(['A','B']);
        $('#ddlPermission').multiselect("refresh");
  });
 
});
/*
     $(".myfunction").click(function(){ 
     var allVal=$("#ddlPermission").val();
  alert(allVal);
  return false;
   
   });
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<input class="form-control btn-primary clickbutton" type="button" name="select" id="select" value="Click">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<select id="ddlPermission" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="permission_ddl">
  <option value="201">headone</option>
  <option value="202">headtwo</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"  class="button active myfunction" value="Submit">
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ramumothukuri/kxbbtgwL/)**

Comment: `You append data to multiselect not select option` not sure what that is intended to mean as `.multiselect` and `#ddlPermission` are the same element

Comment: Aw.. that was my mistake, thanks for the tip @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: out put not showing getting error while i have run the code snippet

Comment: @ramu saying 'I get an error' is absolutely *useless* information. Tell us *what the error is*.

Comment: @ramu Because i didn't include those library here, It works good on `JSFiddle` but now snippet works too.

Comment: Thanks Pedram, McCrossan. Sorry, my bad it's working now after i have place the above initialization

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('#ddlPermission').multiselect('refresh');
```

See this fiddle in action: https://jsfiddle.net/kxbbtgwL/3/

Comment: When OP can move the code before `initialize` why should do `rebuild` ?